# WPF Display ListView in tabs of TabControl with different content

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, datatemplate, tabcontrol

I am trying to display a WPF `ListView` in a tab of TabControl. I am trying to achieve the following: if I click on a button, a new `TabItem` should be created and in that `TabItem` a `ListView` should be shown with its own content.

So if I click on another button, a new tab item should be created and the `ListView` in this second tab item should display another content.

I am setting the `DataContext` to display items in the list view. The lines in the list view are displayed like this:

XAML:

```
<GridViewColumn Width="1500">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding myLine}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

The listview is displayed like this:

```
<TabControl x:Name="tabControl" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="372" Margin="10,32,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="894">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyTab}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding _header}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyTab}">
            <ListView x:Name="myListView" ...></ListView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

How can I display various tabs with their own content?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to bind your list of tabs from your DataContext to `TabControl.ItemsSource`.

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}"/>
```

And on your DataContext have a property called Tabs that is a list or collection of your datatypes;

```
public IList<MyTab> Tabs { get; private set; }
```

Comment: Will I be able to use the same ListView to display different content, and be able to switch between tabs correctly?

Comment: No, each Tab will get it's own ListView, because of your use of DataTemplates.

Comment: I think that will cause problems because my ListView is data virtualizing, and in XAML I have 1 ListView with a name that is set (myListView). Is it possible to use a single listview to display different (file) content?

Comment: I think it is possible to create a new `ListView` **programmatically** and then set a `ItemContainerStyle` that is declared in XAML.. so each ListView will have the same characteristics.

Comment: I think with what you're asking @DrGrid that you don't want to use a `TabControl`. Just add some buttons and change the contents of your `ListView` based on pressing those buttons, and then style those buttons as if it is a `TabControl`.

Comment: @DrGrid Why do you need everything to be in the same named ListView?